# can "or" be used in the logical test for a while loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, comparison, logical-operators

Not sure why this only seems to work with the response "yes"(or "Yes"/"YES") - any help would be appreciated. Pretty new to this!

```
var yesNo = window.prompt("Are you from Earth?");

var lowerYesNo = yesNo.toLowerCase();

while (lowerYesNo != ("yes" || "no")){
    yesNo = window.prompt("Please answer with \"Yes\" or \"No\". Are you from Earth?");
    lowerYesNo = yesNo.toLowerCase();
}

switch (lowerYesNo){
    case "yes":
        window.alert("I thought so!");
        break;
    case "no":
        window.alert("Capture the alien!!!");
        break;
    default:
        window.alert("I don't know how you got this to display!");
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answers, which definitely provide enough when the only options are "yes" and "no", you could also do: `while (["yes", "no"].indexOf(lowerYesNo) === -1) {` *or* `while (!(lowerYesNo in {"yes": 1, "no": 1})) {` *or* `while (!{"yes": 1, "no": 1}[lowerYesNo]) {`, although there are some caveats to each

Comment: Hint: `("yes" || "no")` is equivalent to `true`.

Comment: @Ian Or simply `while(!/^(yes|no)$/.test(lowerYesNo))`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Very true! (personally I don't like a regex here when the list of valid values gets big, but definitely fits for this scenario) Just thought I'd add some of the first ones that came to my head. Feel free to continue adding fun alternatives :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"yes" || "no"
```

returns "yes", because it is a "truthy" value and therefore the first operand of `||` is returned.

If you want to compare to both values, you will need to split this into two separate comparisons:

```
while (lowerYesNo != "yes" && lowerYesNo != "no")) {
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write that is

```
while (lowerYesNo !== 'yes' && lowerYesNo !== 'no') {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, 
((lowerYesNo != "yes") && (lowerYesNo != "no")){

Answer (score 0):

what you probably wanted to do was:

```
while (!(lowerYesNo == "yes" || lowerYesNo == "no")){
    ...
```

that's same as

```
while (lowerYesNo != "yes" && lowerYesNo != "no"){
    ...
```

Meanwhile, take note:

```
(x || y) // this expression will return x, if x is truthy otherwise y
```

and

```
(x && y) // this expression will return x, if x is falsy, otherwise it returns y
```

Hence the loop in your question is equivalent to this:

```
while (lowerYesNo != "yes"){
    ... // you must say "yes" else you're stuck in here.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can be but it needs to be a whole expression

```
while( expression1 || expression2)
```

So in your case it would be

```
while (lowerYesNo != "yes" || lowerYesNo != "no")
```

though as has been pointed out in this instance you probably want to use an &&, since you are trying to print the message only if it is (NOT yes AND NOT No)

Comment: `lowerYesNo != "yes" || lowerYesNo != "no"` is always true.  It should be `&&`

Comment: User asked for || in while, I didn't read the expressions. Whoops

Comment: I almost made the same mistake myself :-)

Answer (score -1):

Because evaluation of the expression

```
 "yes" || "no"
```

results in

```
 "yes"
```

according to javascript rules in evaluating the "or" operator.